# No me marca el total, pero no me manda ningun error ni nada

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras y ya supe supe como hacerlo pero hala hora de cambiar los datos manualmente es decir cambiar la cantidad de productos que el cliente quiere comprar borrando y volviendo a poner el numero que desea, dando click en enter solo me cambia el subtotal pero el total me lo deja tal y como estaba, pero tampoco me marca ningun error es como si no estuviera leyendo ese archivo y no se porque.

este es mi archivo del carrito de compras.

**carritodecompras.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include 'conectar.php';
   if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
    if(isset($_GET['id_producto'])) {
      $arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];
       $encontro=false;
       $numero=0;
       for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){
        if($arreglo[$i]['Id_producto']==$_GET['id_producto']){
            $encontro=true;
            $numero=$i;
        }
       }     
       if($encontro==true){
        $arreglo[$numero]['cantidad']=$arreglo[$numero]['cantidad']+1;
        $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
       } else{
        $nombre="";
        $precio=0;
        $image="";
        $id_producto = $_REQUEST['id_producto'];
                 $re = $Conexion->prepare ("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE Id_producto = '$id_producto'");
                $re->execute();
          $resultado = $re->fetchAll();
                 foreach ($resultado as $producto) {
                   $nombre=$producto['Descripcion'];
                   $precio=$producto['Precio'];
                   $image=$producto['Foto'];
            }
            $datosNuevos=array('Id_producto' => $_GET['id_producto'], 
              'Descripcion' => $nombre,
              'Precio' => $precio,
              'Foto' => $image,
              'cantidad' =>1);
            array_push($arreglo, $datosNuevos);
            $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
       }
     }

   }else {
      if (isset($_GET['id_producto'])) {
        $nombre="";
        $precio=0;
        $image="";
        $id_producto = $_REQUEST['id_producto'];
                 $re = $Conexion->prepare ("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE Id_producto = '$id_producto'");
                $re->execute();
          $resultado = $re->fetchAll();
                 foreach ($resultado as $producto) {
                   $nombre=$producto['Descripcion'];
                   $precio=$producto['Precio'];
                   $image=$producto['Foto'];
            }
            $arreglo[]=array('Id_producto' => $_GET['id_producto'], 
              'Descripcion' => $nombre,
              'Precio' => $precio,
              'Foto' => $image,
              'cantidad' =>1);
            $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
      }
   }

?>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Detalles</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <a href="carritodecompras.php" title="ver carrito"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart-check-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M.5 1a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.11l.401 1.607 1.498 7.985A.5.5 0 0 0 4 12h1a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h7a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .491-.408l1.5-8A.5.5 0 0 0 14.5 3H2.89l-.405-1.621A.5.5 0 0 0 2 1H.5zM6 14a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm-1.646-7.646-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L8 8.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708z"/>
</svg></a>
 
  </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center login-page">
                <div class="col-md-12 login-form">
                <center><p class="login-form-font-header"><span><h1>CARRITO DE COMPRAS</h1></span><p></center>

            <section>
            <?php
                $total=0;
                 if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
                       $datos=$_SESSION['carrito'];
                       
                       $total=0;
                       for($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++){
            ?>
                <div class="producto">
                <center>

                   <img src="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Foto']; ?>" width="180">
                   <br>
                  <span><?php echo $datos[$i]['Descripcion'];?></span>
                  <br>
                   <span>Precio: $<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio'];?> MXN</span>
                   <br>
                   <span>Cantidad: 
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['cantidad'];?>"
                    data-precio="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio'];?>"
                    data-id="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Id_producto'];?>"
                    class="cantidad">
                  </span><br>
                   <span class="subtotal">Subtotal: $<?php echo $datos[$i]['cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'];?> MXN</span>
                </center>
                </div>
            <?php
                $total=($datos[$i]['cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'])+$total;

             }
                 }else{
                  echo '<center><h2>El carrito de compras esta vacio</h2></center>';
                 }
                 echo '<center><h2 id="total">Total: '.$total.'</h2></center>';
            ?>  
           <center><a href="bienvenido1.php">Ver productos</center></a>
            </section>
                    
    </body>
</html>
```

El siguiente es mi archivo de javaScript que se encuentra en una carpeta llamada js

**scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cantidad").keyup(function(e) {
        // Primero analiza el evento
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            // Evita que se procese el formulario (si lo hay)
            e.preventDefault();
            // Después analiza el valor
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                let Id_producto = $(this).attr('data-id');
                // Obtener valores enteros
                let Precio = parseInt($(this).attr('data-precio')) || 0;
                let cantidad = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
                // Actualizar subtotal
                $(this).closest('.producto').find('.subtotal').text('Subtotal: $' + (Precio * cantidad));
                $.POST('js/modificarDatos.php', {
                    Id_producto: Id_producto,
                    Precio: Precio,
                    cantidad: cantidad
                }, function(e) {
                    // Esto ya debe funcionar sin problema
                    $("#total").text('Total: ' + e);
                });
            }
        }      
    });
});
```

Y por ultimo esta mi archivo de modificarDatos.php igual en la carpeta de js

**modificarDatos.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
$arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];
$total=0;
$numero=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++) {
    if($arreglo[$i]['Id_producto'] == $_POST['Id_producto']) {
        // Actualizas la cantidad
        $arreglo[$numero]['cantidad'] = $_POST['cantidad'];
    }
    // Incrementas el total
    // total += operación es lo mismo que total = total + operación
    $total += $arreglo[$i]['Precio'] * $arreglo[$i]['cantidad'];
}
$_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
echo $total;
?>
```

En el archivo de java lo puse así pues para ver si me estaba tomando ese archivo puse un alert y no me salia nada asi que le cambie por este y ya me mandaba el alert asi que pienso que tal ves el error puede estar en el de modificar.

Comment: _jQuery_ no encuentra el elemento para actualizar, porque tienes `<h2 id_producto ="total">Total: '.$total.'</h2>` y, en lugar de `id_producto` debería ser solo `id`

Comment: ya le cambie pero sigue sin funcionar, solo de debo cambiar en el archivo carritodecompras.php o en donde mas?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿El error ocurre en `modificarDatos.php`? ¿Puedes explicar qué significan los dos bucles `for` que tienes en ese archivo? ¿Depuraste tus variables en ese punto? ¿Qué contenido tienen?

Answer (score 0):

En `modificarDatos.php` no necesitas dos ciclos, uno es suficiente para buscar el producto a cambiar y calcular el total:

```
$arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];
$total=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++) {
    if($arreglo[$i]['Id_producto'] == $_POST['Id_producto']) {
        // Actualizas la cantidad
        $arreglo[$numero]['cantidad'] = $_POST['cantidad'];
    }
    // Incrementas el total
    // total += operación es lo mismo que total = total + operación
    $total += $arreglo[$i]['Precio'] * $arreglo[$i]['cantidad'];
}
$_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
echo $total;
```

En `carritodecompras.php` crea el contenedor adecuado para el total, el atributo debe ser `id` para que *jQuery* lo reconozca por `$('#total')`:

```
echo '<center><h2 id="total">Total: '.$total.'</h2></center>';
```

**Importante:** Solo puede haber un elemento con `id="total"`, porque los ID deben ser únicos.

Finalmente, en `scripts.js` la lógica es correcta, solo hacen falta algunos detalles:

- Puedes llegar al contenedor del producto con [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- Asegúrate de convertir a número los valores de precio y cantidad con [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para enteros o [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) si se incluyen decimales; al final, se agrega `|| 0` para prevenir cualquier error en la conversión.

**[Edición]**

Te sugiero cambiar la forma de realizar la petición por [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) para tener mejor control y poder ver los errores, en caso de haberlos:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cantidad").keyup(function(e) {
        // Primero analiza el evento
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            // Evita que se procese el formulario (si lo hay)
            e.preventDefault();
            // Después analiza el valor
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                let id_producto = $(this).attr('data-id');
                // Obtener valores enteros
                let Precio = parseInt($(this).attr('data-precio')) || 0;
                let cantidad = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
                // Actualizar subtotal
                $(this).closest('.producto').find('.subtotal').text('Subtotal: $' + (Precio * cantidad));
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'js/modificarDatos.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        Id_producto: id_producto,
                        Precio: Precio,
                        cantidad: cantidad
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        // Actualizar total
                        $("#total").text('Total: ' + data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, stat, msg) {
                        alert('Error en petición: ' + msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        }      
    });
});
```

**Nota:** Estás usando algunas etiquetas obsoletas como `<center>`; lo recomendable es alinear con CSS, por ejemplo:

```
.producto {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por la respuesta pero sigue sin servirme, solo me cambia el subtotal pero el total sigue igual, es como si no me estuviera leyendo el archivo de modificar ya que aunque le ponga cosas que se que deberian de darme un error no me da nada..

Comment: listo ya la edite

Comment: solo aparece una vez

Comment: @AnaTemaxteMontalvo, es probable que haya un error en la petición. Actualicé la respuesta para tratar de detectar el problema.

Comment: si ya la actualice, revisando me di cuenta que al inspeccionar me sale Uncaught TypeError: $.POST is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:15)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)

Comment: @AnaTemaxteMontalvo, cambia esa función por la que te sugerí en la respuesta.

Comment: ya la cambie pero me sale lo mismo